# gis data export

Tags: export

I have finally decided to learn and use blender for some editing work on digital terrain models.
I have a doubt: can't the models I edit be exported in Qgis and Grassgis readable formats?
This is the format possible: geotiff, grid ascii esri, terra aster, for the raster; grib, netcdf, 2dm, 3di, h2i, esri tin, anuga, hec ras, selafin, tuflow, ugrid, xms tin mesh, stanford ply (this last runs, but without correct coordinates)